# Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow..Error in below highlited code

Tags: vb.net

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Compare(PictureBox1.Image, PictureBox2.Image)
End Sub

Public Function Compare(ByVal img1_ As Image, ByVal img2_ As Image) As Double
    Dim pixelNb As Integer = img1_.Width * img1_.Height
    Dim percent As Double = 100
    Dim resized_img2_ As Bitmap = ResizeBitmap(CType(img2_, Bitmap), img1_.Width, img1_.Height)
    For i As Integer = 0 To img1_.Width - 1
        For j As Integer = 0 To img1_.Height - 1
            percent -= ColorCompare((CType(img1_, Bitmap)).GetPixel(i, j), (CType(resized_img2_, Bitmap)).GetPixel(i, j)) / pixelNb
        Next
    Next

    Return percent
End Function

Public Function ResizeBitmap(ByVal b As Bitmap, ByVal nWidth As Integer, ByVal nHeight As Integer) As Bitmap
    Dim result As Bitmap = New Bitmap(nWidth, nHeight)
    Using g As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(CType(result, Image))
        g.DrawImage(b, 0, 0, nWidth, nHeight)
    End Using

    Return result
End Function

Public Function ColorCompare(ByVal c1 As Color, ByVal c2 As Color) As Double
    Return Double.Parse((Math.Abs(c1.B - c2.B) + Math.Abs(c1.R - c2.R) + Math.Abs(c1.G - c2.G)).ToString()) * 100 / (3 * 255)
End Function
```

Error Give in this line

```
Return Double.Parse((Math.Abs(c1.B - c2.B) + Math.Abs(c1.R - c2.R) +
           Math.Abs(c1.G - c2.G)).ToString()) * 100 / (3 * 255)
```

Comment: I don't catch your error line. What do you want to do there?

Comment: Arithmetic overflow occurs when the result of an operation is too big for the type it is to be stored in.  For instance, if you add two `Integer` values together and the result is larger than `Integer.MaxValue` then the value overflows the variable it is to be stored in.  Use the debugger and you will see exactly where the issue is, i.e. don't just READ the code, actually EVALUATE the expressions as it is being executed.

Comment: i want matching percentage of two image using this code but give error...arithmatic overflow

Comment: Learn how to debug [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y740d9d3.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

Comment: yes sir ...this code debug but not understand problem

Comment: Also, how can it possibly make sense to add three numbers together, convert the result to a `String`, then convert that back to a number?  That's ludicrous.  NEVER convert anything that is not text to a `String` unless it is specifically required to be text, i.e. for display or serialisation or the like.  Maths is performed on numbers so everyhting should be a number all the time.

Comment: No, you haven't debugged your code.  If you had you'd know exactly what expression was causing the issue.  Running you application is not debugging.

Comment: This code get from internet but not solved and not understand errror

Comment: That is exactly why you should debug it sufficiently. _"Debugging"_ doesn't mean that you let the error throw and you just look at it. Google the error to get a grasp of what could be the underlying cause, then step-through your code and inspect variables to find the _actual_ cause. Refer to the link jmcilhinney gave you. Do your research and attempts first, ask questions later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

c1.B returns a byte. A Byte has a value of 0-255 and is unsigned so it cannot hold a negative value.

```
Dim a As Byte = 200
Dim b As Byte = 201
Dim x  = a - b
```

causes the same overflow error.
Changing to an integer avoids the error. A cast doesn't seem to be necessary as it is widening (no data loss).

```
    Dim a As Byte = 200
        Dim b As Byte = 201
        Dim c As Integer = a
        Dim d As Integer = b
        Dim x = c - d
```

Change your color bytes to Integers and try again.

```
Dim g, h, i, j, k, l As Integer
g = c1.B
h = c2.B
i = c1.R
j = c1.R
k = c1.G
l = c1.G
Dim result As Double = CDbl(Math.Abs(g - h) + Math.Abs(i - j) + Math.Abs(k - l)) * 100 / (3 * 255)
    Return result
```

Comment: But I want to Compare Two finger Print image using minutiae matching if any idea or code for c# or VB.net then Please Give ...Using Above code..not give proper Answer.